# How can I determine if the Shift key is down?

Tags: lua, scintilla, scite

I am trying to modify the behavior of one of the built in tools in the AutoIt editor (based on SciTE/Scintilla) which uses Lua scripting. I am using Windows 7.

How can I determine if a shift key is down in Lua?

Comment: This may help. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15283104/using-lua-to-detect-a-combination-of-keyboard-key-presses

Comment: The Lua standard library doesn't know anything about your keyboard - the only IO it does iw via character streams. You will need to look at the AutoIt scripting API to see if it exposes something you can use to solve your problem.